# How to write stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am learning how to write a stored procedure. I kinda get it but I don't.
I know it goes something like this..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE|PROC <sproc name>
[<parameter name> [schema.]<data type> [VARYING] [=<default value>] [OUT[PUT]]
[READONLY]
[,<parameter name> [schema.]<data type> [VARYING] [=<deafult value>] [OUT[PUT]]
[READONLY]
[,...
  ...
   ]]
[WITH 
  RECOMPILE|ENCRYPTION|[EXECUTE AS{ CALLER|SELF|OWNER|<'user name'>}]
[FOR REPLICATION]
AS
 <code> | EXTERNAL NAME <assembly name>.<assembly class>.<method>
```

So what I am stuck on and I am trying to understand is this.. Write a stored procedure that accepts a Territory ID, Territory Description, and Region ID and inserts them as new row in the Territories table in Northwind.

Ok so I know I could do something like this I believe:

```
USE Northwind
GO
CREATE PRO spTerritory
AS
SELECT Territory ID,Territory Description,RegionID
From dbo.Territories
```

But then I can be wrong. But I dont know where to insert then as a new row in the table. I know I would use something like @newrow or @rows along that line. If someone can help me understand who to do a sproc I would be greatful.

Comment: Never name a stored proc starting with  sp, that is used by Microsoft for system storedprocs and you will lose execution time every time it runs because it has to check for a system proc first.

Comment: @HLGEM -- It's `sp_` that's the problem prefix. Using simply `sp` is fine and won't cause the same problems, although you might want to avoid it as a standard convention just in case an `sp_` slips in.

Comment: @ChrisJ, you are correct

Comment: How about, don't start the name with "sp" because it's just silly ;)

Comment: I am sorry about the sp name the reason I use it because that is how it is stated in my book

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for the [INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTerritory (
     @territoryId int
    ,@territoryDescription nvarchar(200)
    ,@regionId int)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Territories (Id, [Description], RegionId)
    VALUES (@territoryId, @territoryDescription, @regionId)

END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft How to: [Create a Stored Procedure (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

USE [SchoolData]
GO

For getting the all data

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create procedure [dbo].[GetDepartment]
as
select Id,Name,Description,IsDeleted from Departments
where IsDeleted=0