# Creating stored procedure getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Declare'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have no idea why I am getting this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_cloud_ClientAllSearch, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Declare'.

Because I have declared the variable.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_cloud_ClientAllSearch]
    DECLARE @Search NVARCHAR(30)

    SELECT 
        client_Name, client_Surname, client_CompanyName, 
        clientContact_TelephoneNo, clientContact_MobileNo, 
        clientAddress_PostalCode
    FROM 
        cloud_Client c
    JOIN
        dbo.cloud_ClientAddresses a ON a.client_ID = c.client_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        cloud_ClientContact cc ON cc.client_ID = c.client_ID
    WHERE 
        c.client_Name LIKE @Search + '%' OR
        c.client_Surname LIKE @Search + '%' OR
        cc.clientContact_MobileNo LIKE @Search + '%' OR
        a.clientAddress_PostalCode LIKE @Search + '%'
```

Comment: You need the word `AS` before the line with `DECLARE`.  Although you never `SET` your variable.  Maybe you mean to pass it in as a parameter?  In which case, get rid of `DECLARE`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082018/how-to-write-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@search` should be an input parameter of the stored proc, (no `Declare` required), and you need an `As` between the signature block for the stored proc and the body of the proc.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_cloud_ClientAllSearch]
 @Search NVARCHAR(30)
As

   SELECT client_Name, client_Surname, client_CompanyName, 
        clientContact_TelephoneNo, clientContact_MobileNo, 
        clientAddress_PostalCode
   FROM cloud_Client c
       Join dbo.cloud_ClientAddresses a
          ON a.client_ID = c.client_ID
       LEFT JOIN cloud_ClientContact cc
          ON cc.client_ID = c.client_ID
   WHERE c.client_Name LIKE @Search + '%' or 
         c.client_Surname LIKE @Search + '%' or 
        cc.clientContact_MobileNo LIKE @Search + '%' or 
         a.clientAddress_PostalCode LIKE @Search + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic structure of SQL Proc.
If u are declaring some variable, it should be between 'As begin' and 'End'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
[(parameter_name [IN | OUT] )]
AS
BEGIN

   Declare .....
   <Proc Body>

END ;
```

After looking at your proc i conclude that,@search is not an variable.It is an input parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_cloud_ClientAllSearch]
(
@Search NVARCHAR(30)
)
As begin 
    .....
END
```